# How can I invoke a function locally using Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function locally for testing, however, my function is created within a `construct`, so i'm getting error: `Function callPSI doesn't exist in this Service` when I try to invoke it.

How can I run this function locally?

**Serverless**

```
constructs:
  jobs:
    type: queue
    name: ${sls:stage}-addToURLQueue
    worker:
      handler: lambdas/callPSI/index.handler
```